# Show that $\mu(\{f(x) > 0\})=0 \iff \mu(\{f(x) > t \}) = 0$ For every $t > 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure-space and $f : X \to \Bbb [0, \infty]$ a unsigned measurable map. Show that $\mu(\{f(x) > 0\})=0 \iff \mu(\{f(x) > t \}) = 0$ For every $t > 0$.

Suppose that $\mu(\{f(x) > 0\})=0  $. Since $f = 0$ a.e we have that $\int_X f = 0$. Thus $\mu(\{f(x) > t\}) \le \frac{1}{t} \int_X f = 0$ and since the measure is positive we have that $\mu(\{f(x) > t\}) = 0$.

Conversely suppose that $\mu(\{f(x) > t \}) = 0 $. Then what can be done for this case? It seems that I could write $\int_X f = \int_{X \setminus \{f(x) > t \}} f+ \int_{\{f(x) > t \}}f$ and the latter integral would be zero, but I don’t really get anywhere from here?

Comment: Your proof for the "easy" direction is correct, but it is strange/an overkill to use  integration to prove this. It is just the fact that $\{x: f(x)>t \} \subseteq \{x: f(x)>0\}$ and monotonicity of the measure.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\{f(x) > 0\}=\bigcup_{n\ge1}\{f(x) > 1/n\}$, it holds
$$
\mu(\{f(x) > 0\})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\{f(x)>1/n\})=0
$$
since the sequence of set $A_n=\{f(x) > 1/n\}$ is increasing.